# Is it a common practice to wrap all page content in a form inside a top-level template?

Tags: templates, jsf, facelets

There is a top-level template in my project and it defines several sub-templates nested in a form:

```
<h:form>
   <ui:insert name="header"/>
   <ui:insert name="leftbar"/>
   <ui:insert name="maincontent"/>
</h:form>
```

It's not my idea actually to build application in this way. I see both its advantages and disadvantages.

The biggest problem I've met is necessity of 2 forms on 1 page: first with default `enctype` and second for uploading files. The second biggest problem is validating unnecessary fields (but it can be relatively easily solved by disabling validation on those fields with jstl `c:if`).

I'm using JSF and Facelets currently but the described design is possible with any templating framework.

So, what I wanted to ask: how do you think is it worth to use this wrapper-form? Is is a common practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly is not. You're now using one "super-form" for *all* actions in the page. This is not the common practice. Every *related* group of input elements should be placed in **its own** form. You don't want to validate/submit your contact form in the main content if you submit the search form in the header.

Comment: I have the same feeling actually.

Comment: I'm in agreement.  Uber-form is bad.